# WrapPanel display item width + static width?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, wrappanel

On a listview, I would like to display each item as their width, with the addition of a static width. So if the item's width is 20, and I'd like to add a space of 15 between each item (making that item's width as 35), how do I do that? I have this code set up for the width, but I can't seem to change it to display anything else other than the width of the item, it doesn't let me do additions like "+50." Unless there is a different way to add this spacing between items.

```
    <WrapPanel 
    Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth), 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}"

    ItemWidth="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemWidth, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
    />
```

I don't want to make ItemWidth a static number itself because it just cuts off my text: https://i.stack.imgur.com/He9Ef.jpg

Comment: If it's dynamic content, and were me, I'd probably just make an ItemsControl with WrapPanel as the ItemsPanelTemplate and throw margins onto the ItemTemplate.

Comment: I realized that ItemsPanel and ItemsTemplate are different things, and I did just what you said and it works (just used Padding instead of margins). Still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your items really need to be x units bigger, use [Padding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751709(v=vs.110).aspx). If you want your items to be separated by x units, use margins (from the same link as padding)

Padding can only be applied to certain elements though so you may have to adjust your templates to make use of it